# Crazy stack trace

Tags: windows, crash-dumps

I've added app hang detector to my Windows app recently. All it does - crashes my app in case it detects that app hang.
In main window's procedure I update last time it was called.
In a separate thread I check if the last time was not updated during 60 seconds.
Note that I create this checking thread in main window's procedure. Not earlier.

Now I received the dump.

Main thread's stack is something crazy. All it shows is this:

```
ntdll.dll!_KiFastSystemCallRet@0()
ntdll.dll!_NtWaitForSingleObject@12()
ntdll.dll!_NtQueryInformationProcess@20()
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()
```

BaseThreadInitThunk is present. But where is my code?

All symbols for my and system's modules are loaded.

If my code would not be called - app hung detector not crashed my app. So my code must be called. But where is it?

Comment: If you go looking for crazy ways in which an app can deadlock and hang then you're apt to find it.  That thread didn't start executing your code yet.

Comment: It did. Because it's main thread and it created several service threads in my app, which works fine and stack trace for them is ok.

Comment: The kernel does play stack switching games with threads.  Running a 32-bit app on a 64-bit version of Windows can be interesting as well.

Comment: Stack switching games with threads? Could you please provide some details?

Comment: Have you tried using _Application Verifier_ to trap the hang condition?

Comment: No. The problem is not in the hang. The problem is in this stack trace. I would like to understand the reason.

Comment: Note. This is just the one of the anonymous automatic reports users send to us.